# "What homework is for?" vs. "What for is homework"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I was asked to write a sentence from the words: **for  / what / is / homework**. Since the using of prepositions in the end of the sentence isn't the strongest part of my knowledge, I found it a little bit tricky, and I'd like to ask if I can write two correct sentences from them:

> 1. What homework is for?
> 2. What for is homework?

Comment: The first sentence should either be a statement (not a question), or it should be *What **is** homework for?* As for the second sentence, the only way it makes any sense is if you paraphrase the grammar of Shakespeare: *Homework, homework, what for is homework?* And even then it would be a strained comparison—as well as something not normally said.

Comment: Believe me, I really don't understand what the first sentence means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your sentences is correct. The correct answer should be:

> What is for homework?

... which is asking: "What are we getting as homework?"

Another example would be "What's for dinner?", which means "What are we having for dinner?"

The phrase "what homework is for" can be used as an object:

> Practice is **what homework is for**.

... to answer this question:

> What **is** homework for?